# laravel 4 Undefined index: password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

My code used to work properly but now there is an error

> (ErrorException (E_NOTICE)Undefined index: password)

I really dont know why, so if you know please help me. I searched google for similar exceptions and try everything I see but still no success ... Here is my code

route.php

```
Route::resource('login', 'LoginController');
```

LoginController

```
        public function store(){

        /*$credentials = array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password')),
        );*/

        if(Auth::attempt(['active' => 1])) {

           // if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){

            if(Auth::attempt(Input::only('username', 'password'))){

                return Auth::user();
                //return Redirect::back()->with('message','You are now logged in!');
                //return Redirect::to('/')->with('message','You are now logged in!');
            }
            else{
                //$errors = ['password' => "Username and/or password invalid."];
               //return Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput(Input::except('password'));
                return 'Failed~';
            }
        }
        else{
            //$errors = ['password' => "Please check your email to activate your account"];
            //return Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput(Input::except('password'));
            return 'Failed~';
        }
    }
}
```

View login/create.blade.php

```
@section('content')
    <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="form col-lg-6 box">

      {{ Form::open(['route' => 'login.store'], array('class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}

     {{--  @if ($error = $errors->first('password'))
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{ $error }}
            </div>
        @endif--}}
        <div class="input-group form-group-md">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            {{ Form::text('username', null,['class' => 'form-control','autofocus'=>'autofocus', 'placeholder' => 'Username']) }}
        </div>
        <div class="input-group form-group-md">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
            {{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password')) }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group-md">
            <a href="/home" class="link">Forgot your password?</a>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-md">
            {{ Form::submit('Log In', array('class' => 'login navbar-btn btn-block form-control', 'autofocus'=>'autofocus')) }}
        </div>

        <div class="question form-group-md">
            {{ Form::label('register', 'Do not have an account?! ') }} <a href="{{ url('users/create') }}" class="link">Register here!</a>
        </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"> </div>
@stop
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzIiE.jpg)

Comment: this error in which line no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your code as below.

```
$username = Input::get('username');
$password = Input::get('password');
// You also may add extra conditions to the authenticating query
if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1)))
{
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}else{
    // user not exist or suspended
}
```

Refer this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security) also.

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `validateCredentials` method which is belongs to your class provider `EloquentUserProvider` expects that the `$credentials` array have array element called `password` and expects it to be hashed .

as shown [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/565456d89e8d6378c213edb7e9d0724fa8a5f473/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php#L113) :

```
/**
* Validate a user against the given credentials.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
* @param  array  $credentials
* @return bool
*/
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];
    return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
}
```

and you in your code are sending wrong array in the first attempt call

`if(Auth::attempt(['active' => 1]))`

to solve this you may have to rewrite your code some thing like this ,

```
public function store()
{
    $credentials = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password')),
        'active' => 1
    );

    if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return Auth::user();
    } else {
        return 'Failed~';
    }
}
```